# OBJ C - error: no type or storage class may be specified here before 'interface'

Tags: objective-c

I have fresh .h .m .xib files, and on compile next to the interface declaration I get:
Problem in another file maybe?  the @end is in place.  Same results when UIKit is the only import.

error: no type or storage class may be specified here before 'interface'

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   #import "NavigationDelegate.h"
   #import "ErrorDelegate.h"


@interface PortraitFrontViewController : UIViewController {

}
@end
```

EDIT:
PortraitFrontViewController.h:

```
#import "PortraitFrontViewController.h"


@implementation PortraitFrontViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: If there’s an error even if you `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` only, it could be the case that there’s something wrong in your prefix header file (.pch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Never mind, OP made a mistake posting the code. Will update this answer when the other file is posted.

Comment: Sorry that was a mess up when I was posting.

Comment: oh. Then can you post the two files that you're importing.

Comment: oh wait, you said you get the same result without those. Can you post the PortraitFrontViewController.m file.

Comment: :) thanks for taking a look.  It's the default xcode generated .m file

Comment: if you start from scratch and create a new project do you get the same error?